# Selecting Multiple element with condition with toggle approach

Tags: ember.js

In my list, I have more than 5 fruit. user can select max as 5 fruit. once the 5 fruits reach, I would like to show them a `alert` to say your 5 selection is over.

also, user can deselect the fruit already which they selected, by clicking again ( toggling )

how to achieve this?

Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedIndex:null,
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
   actions:{
    select:function(index){
     console.log('index is', index );
    }
  }
});
```

here is my try :
[Live Demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/1803ca5bafd1f0581290b1b1da893dc0?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Any one help me here?

Comment: The twiddle just displays a list. Any solution will depend on how you want to do the selecting and how to store the selection. As it stands, this looks like a "please write code for me" instead of a "I am having trouble at a specific point" question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of selected indices and go from there.

```
import Ember from 'ember'

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Twiddle',

  selected: [],

  actions: {
    toggle(index) {
      const indexOf = this.selected.indexOf(index)

      if (indexOf >= 0) {
        this.selected.splice(indexOf, 1)
      } else {
        if (this.selected.length >= 5) {
          return alert('You cannot select more than 5 fruits')
        }

        this.selected.push(index)
      }

      this.notifyPropertyChange('selected')
    }
  }
})
```

Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/39ed50c0d4aae9c45c8ad05690ddac28